# Procedure send email

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

My procedure does not want to run, while in my DBMS there is none displayed.

This procedure should send an email.

I had created the same procedure before, it had worked but I had deleted it in the meantime. I think that's the reason for the problem, but I haven't been able to do it since this morning.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "EMAIL_SAMPLE"
(
    P_FROM IN VARCHAR2,
    P_TO IN VARCHAR2,
    P_SUBJECT IN VARCHAR2,
    P_BODY IN VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
apex_mail.send(
    P_FROM => 'x@gmail.com',
    P_TO => P_TO,
    P_SUBJECT => 'Contact',
    P_BODY => P_BODY);
END
EMAIL_SAMPLE;
```

ERROR:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 578
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2057


3.         P_FROM IN VARCHAR2,
4.         P_TO IN VARCHAR2,
5.         P_SUBJECT IN VARCHAR2,
6.         P_BODY IN VARCHAR2
7.     )
```

Thanks for your help.

Valentine

Comment: Simple `;` after the `END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the wrong signature for apex_mail.send

You call it without a return -> procedure 
As per: 
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/aeapi/SEND-Procedure-Signature-1.html#GUID-B1CD726B-EABE-4A9D-A7A4-3A973E84262D

The signature is p_subj instead of p_subject

So it should be:

```
BEGIN
apex_mail.send(
    P_FROM => 'me@example.com',
    P_TO => 'me@example.com',
    P_SUBJ => 'Contact',
    P_BODY => 'abcd');
END;
/
```

Comment: thanks for your link, it helped me. The error is that the procedure was in capital letters and it is case sensitive. P_FROM is false, write p_from
Thank you